# How can a Master degree lead to 300 ECTS?

Tags: phd, europe

http://emjd-dc.eu/files/2011/11/emjd-dc.pdf

Here, one of the admission requirements is, A Master's degree corresponding to 300 ECTS.

How is that possible?

A Masters degree is at most of 2 years. 2 years = 4 semesters.

1 semester = 5 courses = 5 * 6 = 30 ECTS.

Then, 4 semesters = 30 * 4 = 120 ECTS.

Where does 300 ECTS come from?

Comment: Bzw, not all courses are worth 6 credits and not all programs plan 5 courses per semester.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing ECTS is the [European Credit Transfer and Accumulation System](http://www.studyineurope.eu/ects-system). From that page, a bachelor's degree is worth 180-240 ECTS credits, and the master's is worth 60-120.

It sounds as though the institution you're interested in wants a master's degree and at least 300 ECTS credits. From the linked page, it's possible that you could have a master's but still only have 240 ECTS.

Comment: A bit of history: Before bachelor & master Germany and some other countries just had "Diplom" which took ~5 years. When Bologna came, these programs had to be split in two. A bachelor is supposed to be work-qualifying and some programs decided that you couldnt possibly be qualified after 3 years so they offer a 4 year bachelor and to make up for that a 1 year master. This requirement just makes sure you dont take a 3 year bachelor and then switch to a university with a 1 year master.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. bachelor degree is 180 ECTS, plus master degree 120 ECTS it is European Credit Transfer system or Bologna process declaration, when EU established some common core system for all member states. ( countries ) If you are still applying for ULJ, or anywhere in EU, ( maybe not England since they are not strict part of BP ) They have 180 ECTS plus 120 for master.